# How does Appium inspect the UI of an iOS app to show the view hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, ios, appium, appium-ios

Can someone guide me where on how or where to even begin?

I tried to look at Appium's GitHub repository, but all their code is in javascript which left me highly confused.
Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the uiautomatorviewer to inspect the UI of an ios app. It will give you the full xpath of that particular element which you want to inspect.